# What program to use for reverse MIDAS?

Tags: programming, statistics, econometrics

I know EViews is used for mixed-data sampling (MIDAS). Can someone pls help me identify a program I can use for reverse MIDAS? Thank you.

Comment: I think it is OK to ask this here but I reckon you are more likely to get an answer or a better answer in either of the Cross Validated or Economics Stack Exchange sites than here. Pls don't forget to delete your question here if you post this question in any of those sites as cross-posting among Stack Exchange sites is discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

### `Midasr` in R:

**`R` has a package called [midasr](https://github.com/mpiktas/midasr)** that contains econometric methods for working with mixed-frequency data. One of the authors has another GitHub repository that provides examples on how to fit different reverse MIDAS regressions (*see **[Reverse MIDAS repository](https://github.com/mpiktas/reverse-midas)** with a corresponding **[example document](https://mpiktas.github.io/reverse-midas/reverse_midasr_example.html)***), specifically, the reverse unrestricted MIDAS (RU-MIDAS) of [Xu et al (2018)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610918.2018.1563148?journalCode=lssp20) and the reverse restricted MIDAS (RR-MIDAS) of [Foroni et al (2018)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0169207018300967?via%3Dihub). You can take a look at the package and see if it satisfies your needs.

Lastly, the same author frequents [Cross Validated Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) under the account name **[mpiktas](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/2116/mpiktas)**. For any inquiries about the package or your problem, it would be best to ask there.